# element.style{} when using popup and filter js

Tags: javascript, mixitup

I use MixItUp Js to create a filter for my product, I have a popup
When opening the web to default, the filter is not selected, then element.style {} has an additional attribute:

`transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);`
`transition: opacity 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1) 0.1s, transform 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1) 0.1s;`

[image]

Make the popup part error

[image]

When changing the filter, the new popup is back to normal

[image]

I tried editing in js as follows:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("services__card");
// Get the current value of the style . attribute
let currentStyle = element.getAttribute("style");
// Remove transform and transition properties from current value
let updatedStyle = currentStyle.replace(/transform:.*?;/g, "").replace(/transition:.*?;/g, "");
// Update new style value for element
element.setAttribute("style", updatedStyle);
```

The popup is working, but the filter is not working.